# How to mock `AVFoundation` authorization in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I use the static function `AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video)` to check for camera permission (as discussed [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/capture_setup/requesting_authorization_for_media_capture_on_ios))

In ObjC it's pretty easy to mock it using OCMock and force it to return `.authorized` case. However, OCMock does not support swift. I am wondering how to solve it?

Edit:

Please do not close this question. The "duplicate" [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45372665/swift-unit-tests-mock-class-static-method) provided does not solve the issue because that link is about a custom class defined by yourself, and not a system API, and it does not work.

Comment: How to solve what?

Comment: @cora how to solve the problem with "mocking AVFoundation authorization in swift"

Comment: @cora The link you provided does not answer my problem. That link is about a class that you implement by yourself

Comment: Please do not close this question. The link you provided does not help @cora

Comment: @Cristik interestingly I did not see the one who closed this question (sorry @cora). (and there's no way for me to reject the link).